# Facebook FQL Get approved friends from feed

Tags: graph, facebook-fql

I am able to fetch all the feed and than find the posts which have "approved_friend" as status_type.

I was wondering about, is there any way to filter feed by using fql such as;

select [columns] from [feed] where status_type="approved_friend"

So that i could only fetch approved friend posts from my feed.

I will appreciate any help that you guys would provide.

Thanks in advance,